# ssh script doesn't work

Tags: ssh, scripting

Hi guys I need some help, I wrote a script to connect to multiple ssh hosts but the script only work with the first IP the other ones didn't change.
Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTS="192.168.120.237 192.168.120.238 192.168.120.239"
USER=root

# Conectar a cada una de las IP
for host in $HOSTS; do 
  ssh "$USER@$HOSTS" 'bash -s arg' < /home/soulfly/Escritorio/neo1isla1.sh
done
```

Comment: `$HOSTS` is a string, but you're using it (well, trying to use it) as an array. My Bash knowledge is limited, but I don't think it'll work like that.

Comment: @ceejayoz bash will split a string in a loop like that using the internal field separator ($IFS).  So a string will be broken up.  Try running `var='one two three four' ; for a in $var ; do echo "- $a" ; done`

Answer (score 2):

Try `ssh "$USER@$host"` instead of `$HOSTS`.  The `$HOSTS` contains the list of all the addresses.